# Search in string and replace with a value from a list in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, find

```
my_string = """"
Hello [placeholder],

I would [placeholder] to work with you. I need your [placeholder] to complete my project.

Regards,
[placeholder]
"""

my_lst = ['John', 'like', 'help', 'Doe']
```

**I want to put this value of the list into my_string.**

So, my_string would be:
*"""
Hello John,
I would like to work with you. I need your help to complete my project.
Regards,
Doe """*

**Here, number of [placeholder] and length of the list would be dynamic. So, I need a dynamic solution. That will work for any string regardless number of [placeholder] and length of list. How can I do this in Python? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: `my_string.replace("[placeholder]", "{}").format(*my_lst)` Or simply use `{}` instead of `[placeholder]` and call [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) without any additional replacements. More information about format string syntax [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But sometimes # of [placeholder] and length of the list may not equal. I want to replace [placeholder] with a blank string if the list has not enough value. How can I do that?

Comment: You can subclass [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) and override [`get_value()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.get_value) method to return an empty string if index is greater or equal length of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you can use `re.sub` and lambada to `pop` the items from the list

```
my_string = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)]', lambda x: my_lst.pop(0), my_string)
```

Edit regarding the comment *sometimes # of [placeholder] and length of the list may not equal.*:

You can use empty string in the `lambda` if the list is empty

```
my_string = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)]', lambda x: my_lst.pop(0) if my_lst else '', my_string)
```

Comment: `lambda x, l=my_lst[:]: l.pop(0)`  or `lambda x, l=iter(my_lst): next(l),` could be an alternative *(last is better)* if modifying of `my_lst` isn't allowed.

Comment: `lambda x, l=iter(my_lst): next(l, "")` to follow conditions from comments.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better to use `{}` instead of `[placeholder]` because it will allow you to unpack your list of replacements into default [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) without any additional modifications.

```py
my_string = """\
Hello {},

I would {} to work with you. I need your {} to complete my project.

Regards,
{}\
"""
my_lst = ['John', 'like', 'help', 'Doe']

my_string = my_string.format(*my_lst)
```

If modifying this "template" if not possible, you can do that programmatically using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```py
my_string = my_string.replace("[placeholder]", "{}").format(*my_lst)
```

If amount of *placeholders* could be higher than length of `my_lst`, you may use a custom formatter which will return a default value.

```py
from string import Formatter

class DefaultFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, default=""):
        self.default = default
    
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        if isinstance(key, str) or key < len(args):
            return super().get_value(key, args, kwargs)
        else:
            return self.default

fmt = DefaultFormatter()
my_string = fmt.format(my_string.replace("[placeholder]", "{}"), *my_lst)
```